# JSF: are resource components optimized?

Tags: java, jsf, resources

It doesn't make much of a difference, I know, but in JSF 2 I can output a resource (for instance css), in 1 of two ways:

a) Using the standard html `<link>` component and an absolute path to the component. This is treated as text and is therefore not built into a component.

b) Using the jsf `<h:stylesheet>` and setting its name and library.

Now, if I am writing the main template site, something that won't change (fixed), am I better off using plain text and giving absolute paths to the resources? Is there any change in performance, even if insignificant, between using that and the jsf component?

Does JSF optimize the access to this so that it doesn't have to locate the resource every time the page is rendered?

The same goes for all types of resources, images and javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimization is actually dependent on the JSF implementation used but yes, both Mojarra and MyFaces have highly optimized the performance of resource handling. Every single possibility of server side and client side caching is been accounted. The most accessed resources are cached in server's memory, the I/O transfer goes through channels, the proper `ETag` and `Last-Modified` response headers are been set, etc. In case of Mojarra, a good starting point to check how it's all handled is the `com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl#handleResourceRequest()` method.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot, so in real terms there's absolutely no performance difference between plain text and using the jsf component because of this caching? This is very interesting, I actually thought that using the jsf components to output resources had a performance penalty or something

Answer (score 1):

its not `<h:stylesheet>` but `<h:outputStylesheet>`

JSF components are converted to plain html at the time of render hence when you see the source code of your page you will not find any jsf component all jsf components are automatically converted to according html components.

this tag will be converted to html as follow

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
```

HTML output…

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
   href="/JavaServerFaces/faces/javax.faces.resource/style.css?ln=css" />
```

Warning

```
When render CSS file via <h:outputStylesheet /> tag, remember put the <h:head /> 
tag as well;  Otherwise the css file will not render successful.
```

refer http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/